# C - Find substring in a formatted string

Tags: c

I searched a lot, but could not find the best way to approach the following situation.

I have a array of strings formatted this way :

```
username, password, usertype
```

For example,

```
joseph, secret, user
```

(The array is initially loaded from a file).

I would like to take a user input (`username` and `password` only) and compare to all strings in my array to see if there is a match.

Example

```
user input - (username) joseph     (password) secret
-> matches joseph, secret, user
```

I tried using using substrings and strtok... Is there a standard way of approaching this problem in C?

**Using strstr**

```
/* Search users */
  for (i = 0; i < n_users; i++) {
    if(strstr(users[i], username) != NULL) {
      printf("\t! Found user at %d\n", i);
      break;
    }
  }
```

It is not quite right because if the username if `Bobby`, then `by` would return true...

Comment: show us your attempt..!

Comment: Browse through string.h functions and find your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no standard way, there's certainly a simple solution: if you have your strings in the exact format, it is sufficient to format the two-part string the same as prefix of the strings being searched, and then compare for substring using `strstr`, and verifying that the result returned from `strstr` matches the first string.

Here is how you can make the string for searching:

```
int len = strlen(username)+strlen(passwd)+3; // space, comma, and \0
char *cmpString = malloc(len);
sprintf(cmpString, "%s, %s", username, passwd);
for (i = 0; i < n_users; i++) {
    if(strstr(users[i], cmpString) == users[i]) { // cmpString is a prefix
        printf("\t! Found user at %d\n", i);
        break;
    }
}
free(cmpString);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to split the file string into variables to compare to username and pw. I like your solution better : combine username and pw into a string and then compare to the file string!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strstr` to find a substring. Alternatively you can use `sscanf` to parse the string (that's instead of using `strtok`) and `strcmp` to verify that user actually entered a valid username or password (i.e. detect cases where user enters usertype, or only part of name or password or even something as bad as 'username, password')